# Scaling a fill pattern in svg smoothly

Tags: browser, svg

I'm making a map that is zoomable and pannable using svg (for easier interaction).  I have a grid that other objects (rectangles) can align to.

The grid a rectangle filled with a pattern.  The pattern contains only a rectangle.  Zoom and panning are done via transformations.  The same transformation is applied to the pattern and each element I want to be aligned to the grid.  Translation (pan) works correctly, but zoom (scale) does not.

The pattern only seems to scale at certain intervals, while the other elements scale at each interval.  It's as though the pattern has a much lower precision for it's transformations.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gxz2P/

The code below effectively demonstrates the problem in firefox, chrome, and safari:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
function setMatrix(a,b,c,d,e,f){
    var matrix = [a,b,c,d,e,f];
    matrix = matrix.join();
    matrix = 'matrix(' + matrix + ')';
    document.getElementById('pat').setAttribute('patternTransform', matrix);
    document.getElementById('boxRect').setAttribute('transform', matrix);
}

function startGrow(sleepy){
    if(! sleepy){
        sleepy = 100;
    }
    var grow = function(lastZoom){
        var zoom = lastZoom + 0.01;
        setMatrix(zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0);
        if(zoom < 2){
            setTimeout(function(){
                grow(zoom);
            }, sleepy);
        }
    }

    grow(1);
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="100%" height="1500">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="pat" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <rect x="2" y="2" width="28" height="28" stroke="red" fill="lightblue" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000" fill="url(#pat)" stroke="black" id="gridRect" />
        <rect x="320" y="320" width="32" height="32" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="red" id="boxRect" />
        <rect x="352" y="352" width="32" height="32" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="black" id="staticBox" />
    </svg>
    <script>
startGrow(100);
    </script>
</html>
```

Loading the page in a browser will show how the grid does not scale at the same time as the red bordered box even though they both get the same matrix at the same time.

Is there a way to get a smooth scaling fill pattern, or should I scrape this and try a different approach for the grid?

Comment: As an interesting data point, you see the same results if you smoothly scale the rect that is using the pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/Gxz2P/2/ Also, both your original test and mine using scale work as desired on Opera.

Comment: I'm scaling the pattern so I can easily pan the map as well by simply applying a transform to the pattern, rather than needing to move the grid element around as a I pan.  Setting the transform on the pattern with a large pattern does do a smooth scale, so your solution still works.  Interesting that it works well in Opera; likely a better implementation of patterns.

Comment: Just for more information...

Seems this is a known issue in Chrome/Webkit: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125638

Firefox seems to work fine (in Linux).

Comment: I don't see an issue with Firefox 12 on Vista, assuming I've understood the problem of course. What version of Firefox on which platform are you using that shows problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear to be related to the size of your pattern element scaling on pixel boundaries. If you create a much larger pattern (then what's the point, right?) you do not experience the same problem:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gxz2P/3/